# Twitter Request token always fails with 401 in python

Tags: python, twitter, urllib2, urllib

I am using urllib and urllib2 to get request token from twitter as recommended here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter, code is below. Can anyone see, what am I doing wrong? I get 'urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized'

```
#! env python

import sys                                                          
import os                                                           
import urllib                                                        
import urllib2                                                      
import uuid                                                         
import time                                                         
import base64
import string                                                       

# 1. Obtain a request token                                         
# 2. Redirect the user                                              
# 3. Convert the request token to an access token                   

consumer_key=           "xxxxxxx"                     
consumer_secret=        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# Request token URL:    https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token 
# Authorize URL:        https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize     
# Access token URL:     https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token  

nonce = base64.b32encode(str(uuid.uuid4().hex))                     
# example: MYZTMMRYMEYDQN3FMFSDIYJXGNRDCMBWG42TAMJUGVTGGMZRMFSA====
nonce = nonce.rstrip('=') 
print 'Nonce', nonce                                                

data = { 'oauth_callback'           : 'http://www.gooogle.com',     
         'oauth_consumer_key'       : 'bwKT66akiJSin30L1mGnQ',      
         'oauth_nonce'              : nonce,                        
         'oauth_timestamp'          : int(time.time()),             
         'oauth_version'            : "1.1"                         
}                                                                   

url_values = urllib.urlencode(data)                                 
url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'
full= url + '?' + url_values                       
data = urllib2.urlopen(full)
```

Which all query parameters are mandatory here?

Comment: Not what you asked, but I would HIGHLY recommend you use [Twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython). The library makes it [so damn easy](https://github.com/thekarangoel/What-Would-I-Tweet/blob/master/gen.py#L33-L51) to authenticate Twitter.

Comment: @KaranGoel - Ok will check it out, do you know already, whether, Twython has capabilities of 'Sign in with twitter' functionality?

Comment: http://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/starting_out.html